# Dynamic table going out of the form tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table

I have added a dynamic table on page load as follows

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.ID = "table1";

    this.Controls.Add(tbl);

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        TableRow rw = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();

        Label text = new Label();
        text.Text = "text";

        cell.Controls.Add(text);
        rw.Cells.Add(cell);

        tbl.Controls.Add(rw);
     }
}
```

The problem is, when I inspect the elements in the browser, the table appears to come out of the form tag as follows.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="return TimerStart();">
        <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="trial2.aspx" id="aspnetForm">   
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <table id="table1" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><span>text</span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span>text</span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span>text</span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span>text</span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span>text</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want the table within the form tag, Please help!

Comment: have you tried adding an `overflow:auto;` ??

Comment: Are you using master page? Can we see the page's markup?

Comment: @ Andrei, Yes I m using Master Page, put it has no elements currently.

Comment: create  a placeholder in form and insert table in it

Comment: the thing is you are adding the table by using the this keyword. Which currently refers to the Page... so it added your table to the end of the page. Try adding the control to the form.. which adds to the form..

Comment: @Nathan Lee , I did not get for what should i use Overflow:auto for the table style.

Answer (score 2):

Add your table before `</html>` tag

In ASP.Net better you add it with in form tag with below code

```
this.Form.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

instead of `this.Controls.Add(tbl);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Table tbl = new Table();
tbl.ID = "table1";

Form.Controls.Add(tbl); 
....
```