# Form Tag is misplaced on adding dynamically using jquery in a table as a row

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a HTML Form as a table row dynamically using Jquery 1.3.2 (Please don't ask why such an older version). Hierarchy of tags should be as below since I need the form to be added as a table row.

```
<tr><form><td><input/></td><td><button/></td></form></tr>
```

The issue I am facing is that form tag is coming out of hierarchy

```
<tr><form></form><td><input/></td><td><button/></td></tr>
```

I have already tried some solutions but does not work. e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions/20000198](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000198)

```js
$('#addNewRow').click(function() {
  var form = '<tr id = "id_rowAdd"><form action="add" method="post" id="id_frmAdd">' +
    '<td><input type = "text" cssClass="" name="col1" id="id_col1"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="submit" value="Add" name="addBtn" id="id_addBtn"/></td>' +
    '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" name="rowDeleteBtn" id="id_rowDeleteBtn"/></td></form></tr>';
  $('#scrollTable tr:first').before(form);

});

$('#id_rowDeleteBtn').click(function() {
  $('#id_rowAddFlight').remove();
});
```

```css
div.row_manipulator {
  float: left;
  background-color: #21405d;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
div.row_manipulator a {
  color: #FCFF9D;
  font-family: sans-serif, "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_holder" style="background: #21405d;width: 1228px;margin-top: 5px;">
  <div class="row_manipulator w11">
    <s:a href="#" id="addNewRow">Add New Row</s:a>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: left;">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tbl1 scroll" id="scrollTable">
      <thead id="table_head">
        <tr>
          <th class="w11">Column 1</th>
          <th class="w11">Column 2</th>
          <th class="w11">Column 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Provided below is ***Screenshot of Dynamically Generated HTML*** from Chrome Dev Tool after Clicking the "Add Row" Link.

[image: dynamic generated html screen]

**Can anyone help me point out what i might be doing wrong here and i how i can fix it? Thanks a lot in advance.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can hand code a `<form>` tag inside a `<tr>` and the browser will allow it[1], behind the scenes it is complicated (and the browser is adjusting things for you).

Technically speaking ([W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5)) the only valid children of a `<tr>` are `<th>` and `<td>` elements, so when you try to add a form via JavaScript the browser is likely going to complain.

**TL;DR** you will want to add your form to wrap the entire `<table>` or, add it to be within a specific `<td>` element.

[1]: Re 'allow' - the browser 'accepts' it, but modifies the real DOM it works with to overcome this invalid nesting.

Comment: "*Although you can hand code a `<form>` tag inside a `<tr>` and the browser will allow it*" - really? I'm on mobile currently, so checking this is painful, but I seem to remember that browsers rearrange things, for validity, when constructing the DOM from the invalid html.

Comment: @scunliffe :: add it to be within a specific <td> element -> Doing this I will not be able to use all elements to submit in form. Please note that i have multiple `<TD>` elements, gave only few for sake of simplicity. Also I am not sure putting form tag outside of table can help in my situation as i can have 1000s of rows in my table and I do not want to risk all rows to be submitted to backend.

Comment: @DavidThomas *allow* in this case means you can do it, but the browser will modify the actual DOM that it is using such that it is valid. (e.g. the browser will move the form to wrap the table)... but the visible DOM in the dev tools will still show the invalid nesting.  Sadly most of this started from back in the day when developers didn't want the extra space (margin) above/below forms and they discovered a hack that nesting the form inside a table would remove the margins. Long story short, attempting to nest a form wrapping TR elements will cause trouble even if at first it appears to work

Comment: @rockstar89 I understand... but unfortunately what you are trying to achieve *won't work*.  You likely need to make 1 form that wraps the entire table, and then uniquely name your form elements (added to each TD as needed)... then submit your entire form (or selectively find parts within it, and submit a subset via AJAX)

Comment: I have already done the same with loading few datarows dynamically from backend using a iterator in my JSP page so it is evident that `<FORM>` can be placed inside `<TR>` and browser will not restructure the DOM elements.

Comment: It **looks** like it works, but it doesn't.  This is simply not valid HTML. If you inspect the actual nested DOM that the browser uses (not the view-source, and not the dev tools view) you will find that it modifies the actual DOM to attempt to make your code valid/usable.

Comment: @scunliffe Certainly that is true that it's not valid HTML to put Forms inside table rows where only `<TD>` elements belong. I will look into placing the `<TABLE>` nested by the `<FORM>` but in the meantime will wait for other comments from other community members. Thanks for suggesting an alternative way. I will accept your answer if I cannot find another alternative which will match my requirements and yours work. Thanks once again.

Comment: This should have a million "up votes."  For two days I couldn't figure out why  a dynamic form wasn't submitting.  Hours and hours lost.  Most suggestions were to "bind" the form to the document, which I was already doing.  So, I decided to re-write the code in case there was something I was missing, like a type-o.  On the re-write, I left out the table for simplicity, and it worked fine.  So then, to get formatting back, I re-introduced the table mark-up.  BAM!! The form wouldn't submit again.  I wish I new to even look this up 3 days ago!!